# Two different Styles for Dropdowns in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, stylesheet

So I am creating a dashboard currently using Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to style two separate dropdown menus, everytime I try to change the style for the sidebar navigation to make it different from the main menu navigation dropdown it doesn't pick it up. So the dropdowns work on both navigation's, but I want two separate styles and I can't figure out how to get it working. Thanks!!

Side Bar

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a hdata-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Overview</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                  </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 main">
              <h1 class="sub-header">Edit Content</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Navigation Bar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Application</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Administor</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Reports</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Entities</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Customers</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Marketing</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Monitor</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Info</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Help</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood the issue but If you want to style two different Bootstrap dropdowns I would suggest you add an extra class next to each `dropdown` class like so:

```
<div class="dropdown drop1">
...
<div class="dropdown drop2">
```

And then style each one like so:

```
.dropdown.drop1 {
    // custom style
}

.dropdown.drop2 {
    // custom style
}
```

PS: Watch out for CSS specificity. Make sure you CSS rules are specific enough to overwrite Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Well it's kinda hard to explain I guess, so I have dashboard with a sidebar on the left that has navigation items I want to click and have submenu's show underneath. Then I have a main navigation bar on top of the page with like Home, About, Etc on it with dropdowns that show up when you hover over them. So I want to style those two dropdowns different.. the main menu nav is absolute positioned, the sidebar won't be. Now it just has the dropdown-menu style applied to both and if I add another similar style but rename it and try and use it on the sidebar navigation the dropdown no longer works.

Comment: If you are renaming Bootstrap classes then the Bootstrap styling no longer applies so don't do that. If that's the case then my example still makes sense, add an extra class next to the Bootstrap classes so you can target specific dropdowns in your CSS.

Comment: Okay, I added a secondary style to the dropdown class and it still isn't picking up the style for some reason. <li class="dropdown tree-table"> and the css style is .dropdown.tree-table. It's still picking up the same .dropdown style instead of the secondary style. Here is a jfiddle I made with my original code http://jsfiddle.net/p44rt4xm/.